# Error when deleting project from jenkins

Tags: jenkins

When I am trying to delete a project on jenkins I get the following exception:

```
A problem occurred while processing the request. Please check our bug tracker to see if a similar problem has already been reported. If it is already reported, please vote and put a comment on it to let us gauge the impact of the problem. If you think this is a new issue, please file a new issue. When you file an issue, make sure to add the entire stack trace, along with the version of Jenkins and relevant plugins. The users list might be also useful in understanding what has happened.

Stack trace

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "scm": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:475)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:803)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:381)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:1136)
    at hudson.Launcher$RemoteLaunchCallable.call(Launcher.java:1101)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:121)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:324)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: looks like some inbuilt plugin data got corrupted. What exactly you did before trying to delete this project?

Comment: Nothing special. I ran the job